Using yield in python with no arg, prints don't execute
I have this experimental code:
def f():
   print("Line 1")
   yield

   print("Line 2")
   yield

   print("Line 3")
   yield

f()
f()
f()

All I see on the screen is <generator object f at 0x7d8239c794d0>. I expected that each print statement would execute, then execution pauses at each yield line until f() is called again. But this is not the case, why is that? What am I misunderstanding?

f() returns a generator, it doesn't execute code inside f. You would need to call next on the generator. That is how generators work.

Ok, but why/how? I am baffled that a simple print statement won't execute even if it's before the yield, how come?

Because the body of f doesn't execute -- it is a generator function. That's how they work. Only next causes execution of generator function code. It's like you get a handle to the function by calling it, and then have control over actually executing statements (up until the next yield) with a next call.

I added another link in the top blue banner of this page.

Explicitly, g = f(); next(g); next(g); next(g) will give you the output you expect. Every time you call f you get (and in your example, ignore) a new generator object  which will execute the body of the def statement as you iterate over the generator.

The presence of yield fundamentally changes what the def statement actually does. It was arguably a design mistake to make def do two different things, rather than introduce a new gendef statement that explicitly defines generators.

If the call to f() would proceed to yield, that would mean it would already yield its first value to the caller, so v = f() would assign the value of the first yield to v. But then how do you get the value of the next yield? You don't have a handle on the generator itself anywhere. — That's why f() just returns that handle, so you can successively ask it for its next value.

Thank you, I will read through the links. I've clearly underestimated the idea of yield, it's not as simple.
